# How to delete lines between a pattern when the pattern repeats

Tags: shell, awk, sed, gawk

Have a large `HTML` document where the term for `BEGIN` and `END` are repeated throughout the document.
For example, BEGIN is `<script>` and END is `</script>`.
For each instance of the pattern in the document, there are a variable number of lines between the pattern (between `<script>` and `</script>`).

Have tried the following in `sed`:

```
sed '/\<script>/,/\<\/script>/d'
```

This `sed` string deletes everything between the first occurrence of `<script>` and the **last** occurrence of `</script>`.

Also tried:

```
awk '/\<script>/,/\<\/script>/d'
```

This `awk` string deletes all content between the pattern but, unlike the sed string, preserves every occurrence of the pattern like this:

```
<script>
</script>
```

In summary, I can get a variation of what I want (or its opposite).

- sed deletes text between (one instance of) a pattern
- awk maintains all occurrences of the pattern, but deletes the content between the pattern, as well as content before and after the pattern.

**My question**: using sed or awk (and/or any other GNU utility), how to delete content between a pattern when the terms to define the pattern (the `BEGIN` term and `END` term) occur multiple times within a document?

Comment: `\<` matches the empty string at the beginning of a word. There is no need to escape the `<` character in sed.

Comment: Never use range expressions as they make trivial jobs very slightly briefer but then require a complete rewrite and/or duplicate conditions when the problem becomes even slightly more interesting. Always use flags instead, e.g. `awk '/start/{f=1} f; /end/{f=0}' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another awk alternative

```
awk '/\<script/{p=1};/\/script/{p=0;;next}; !p' file.html
```

Comment: spot on! TY. Would you take an extra moment to document your solution? Several others on this page made good faith efforts to help, but I could not make their proposals work. If you have an opinion why - that would be useful to know. For example, in general, I've found that `awk` is more reliable than `sed` and `join`.

Comment: Careful there - `\<` is a literal `<` preceeded by a useless backslash in some awks and a word boundary delimiter in others. I suspect you just want `<`, not `\<`. Also, clean up the redundant `;`s.

Comment: @JayGray the idea is to use a flag `p` to indicate you're in a script tag or not. `!p` is to print when you're not inside script.  Note that this script is not robust and may not be portable.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat file
a
<script>
b
</script>
c
<script>
d
</script>
e

$ awk '/<script>/{f=1} !f; /<\/script>/{f=0}' file
a
c
e
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` works for me. Are you sure it deleted everything between the first and last occurrence?

```
for i in {1..20} ; do
    echo $i
    (( 0 == i % 7 )) && echo '<script>'
    (( 0 == i % 8 )) && echo '</script>'
done | sed '\=<script>=,\=</script>=d'
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
9
10
11
12
13
14
17
18
19
20
```

To see the removed parts, add a `!` before the `d`:

```
... | sed '\=<script>=,\=</script>=!d'
<script>
8
</script>
<script>
15
16
</script>
```

Comment: That's a formidable example. But I can confirm that in my `HTML` document `sed` seems to loose track of the first occurrence of the END statement (i.e. `</script>`) and deletes to the end of the document. My request is that you pick your favorite HTML document that has multiple javascript declarations and see if you can delete only the multiple occurrence of those declarations, including the opening and closing statements (`<script>` `</script>`)

Comment: OK, I tried this: `sed '/\<script>/,/\<\/script>/!d'`. In this case it deleted all content down to the first occurrence of `<script>`. No further deletions were made.

Comment: In a test HTML file I changed `<script>` to `BEGIN` and `</script>` to END (per your example). Then I ran `sed '/BEGIN/,/END/d'` (not !d). This set of modifications works. It's a pain in the arse but I could apply the above change to the larger HTML file. Hoping someone sees the reason why `sed` is not able to correctly process properly escaped versions of `<script>` and `</script>`.

Comment: @JayGray: Remove the backslash before `<`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
awk '/<script>/,/<\/script>/{next}1'
```

Comment: Am getting a result like the `sed` string.. Specifically, the `awk` string deletes all data after the first occurrence of `<script>` (including the term `<script>`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question, you want to delete all the lines between (as you stated) `BEGIN` and `END` preserving the lines `BEGIN` and `END`.
If so this should work for you:

```
sed  '/\<script>/,/\<\/script>/ { /<script>/n; /\<\/script>/ !{ d; }; }' input_file
```

Input:

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title></title>
<body>
 <script>
SOME SCRIPT
</script>
 <script>
SOME OTHER SCRIPT
 </script>
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title></title>
<body>
 <script>
</script>
 <script>
 </script>
</head>
</body>
</html>
```